# Creating a parser combinator of type Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (Either a b)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I want to parse some text in which certain fields have structure most of the time but  occasionally (due to special casing, typos etc) this structure is missing.

E.g. Regular case is `Cost: 5`, but occasionally it will read `Cost: 5m` or `Cost: 3 + 1 per ally`, or some other random stuff.

In the case of the normal parser (p) not working, I'd like to fallback to a parser which just takes the whole line as a string.

To this end, I'd like to create a combinator of type `Parser a -> Parser b -> Either a b`. However, I cannot work out how to inspect the results of attempting to see if the first parser succeeds or not, without doing something like `case parse p "" txt of ...`.

I can't see a build in combinator, but I'm sure there's some easy way to solve this that I'm missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
eitherParse :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (Either a b)
eitherParse a b = fmap Left (try a) <|> fmap Right b
```

The `try` is just to ensure that if `a` consumes some input and then fails, you'll backtrack properly. Then you can just use the normal methods for running a parser to yield `Either ParseError (Either a b)`

Which is quite easy to transform into your `Either a b`

```
case parse p "" str of
  Right  (Left a) -> useA a
  Right (Right b) -> useB b
  Left   err      -> handleParserError err
```

Comment: Ignore this comment -- I thought of this shorly after posting, but GHC can't trivially unify the a and b in (fmap Left foo) :: Either a b, (fmap Right bar):: Either a b

Comment: @MrBones Can you clarify what you mean? This compiles just fine for me

Comment: I was wrong, I'd not corrected the type signature when I swapped the parameters a and b.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [(<|>) :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/packages/parsec-3.1.3/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3a-60--124--62-)

As a rule you could use it this way:

```
try p <|> q
```

Comment: They want the combinator to support different types.